# How do I define the name of image built with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, orchestration

I'm using [**docker-compose**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/) to create my development environment. I want to build a specific image, but I don't know how to set a name for that image.

```
wildfly:
  build: /path/to/dir/Dockerfile
  container_name: wildfly_server
  ports:
   - 9990:9990
   - 80:8080
  environment:
   - MYSQL_HOST=mysql_server
   - MONGO_HOST=mongo_server
   - ELASTIC_HOST=elasticsearch_server
  volumes:
   - /Volumes/CaseSensitive/development/wildfly/deployments/:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
  links:
   - mysql:mysql_server
   - mongo:mongo_server
   - elasticsearch:elasticsearch_server
```

When I execute `docker-compose` everything is ok, but I get a random name for the new image. Is it possible to set a name to the build image?

Comment: If you're using docker-compose to build the image, the image name is always going to be `<project>_<service>`, where `<service>` in this example is `wildfly` and project defaults to the directory name you're in. You can change that with `-p` or `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable.

There is no way to set a custom image name.

Comment: are there no acceptable answers?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/service-links/ - official document about this subject

Comment: you can also set `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=x` in `.env` and your containers will be called `{x}_{service}_{#}`

Comment: __NOTICE:__ Because Docker container names must be unique, you cannot scale a service beyond 1 container if you have specified a custom name. Attempting to do so results in an error. [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#container_name)

Answer (score 310):

For docker-compose version 2 file format, you can build and tag an image for one service and then use that same built image for another service.

For my case, I want to set up an elasticsearch cluster with 2 nodes, they both need to use the same image, but configured to run differently.  I also want to build my own custom elasticsearch image from my own Dockerfile.  So this is what I did (`docker-compose.yml`):

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  es-master:
    build: ./elasticsearch
    image: porter/elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    container_name: es_master

  es-node:
    image: porter/elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - es-master
    ports:
      - "9200"
    command: elasticsearch --discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=es_master
```

You can see that in the first service definition *`es-master`*, I use the `build` option to build an image from the Dockerfile in `./elasticsearch`.  I tag the image with the name *`porter/elasticsearch`* with the `image` option.
Then, I reference this built image in the *`es-node`* service definition with the `image` option, and also use a `depends_on` to make sure the other container *`es-master`* is built and run first.

Setting the name [constrains scaling](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#container_name).

Comment: The option `container_name:` really helped.

Comment: Are you sure this works? `build` and `image` are mutually exclusive. I get "Service xxx has both an image and build path specified. A service can either be built to image or use an existing image, not both."

Comment: Oh, never mind. Those two can be used together in the v2 format and onwards. The thing I was testing didn't specify a version so I guess was assumed to be v1.

Comment: The option container_name: really helped me thks

Comment: container_name: you_win :)

Comment: @BrunoBieri what is with `container_name`? What does that have to do with one service reusing the image of another?

Comment: @dangonfast with the `container_name` you can specify a containers name within a docker compose file and influence how the named. This allows you to use it as `depends_on` names. For more information read here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name

Comment: @BrunoBieri the `depends_on` uses the name of the service in the `doker-compose` file, no need to specify a container name. Even the example shows it `depends_on: es-master` and not `depends_on: es_master`

Comment: It seems the `environment` is not inheriting to the *sub-services* (***`version: '3.8'`***)

Comment: indeed  we can use `build` and `image` together, docker compose will name the new image with the value of `image` option. but there's a side effect --> it always trying to "pull" the image first(which doesn't exists because it's a custom name), then print error, I tried to remove the `image` option, the "pull" action is gone and there's no error anymore. do you guys met this error too?

Comment: @Willis did you manage to fix this error? i am getting the same one

Comment: @liam No, just leave it, it doesn't affect normal use, maybe that's normal action.

Answer (score 108):

As per [docker-compose 1.6.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.6.0):

> You can now specify both a build and an image key if you're using the new file format. `docker-compose build` will build the image and tag it  with the name you've specified, while `docker-compose pull` will attempt to pull it.

So your `docker-compose.yml` would be

```
version: '2'
services:
  wildfly:
      build: /path/to/dir/Dockerfile
      image: wildfly_server
      ports:
       - 9990:9990
       - 80:8080
```

To update docker-compose

```
sudo pip install -U docker-compose==1.6.0
```

Comment: ERROR: Validation failed, reason(s):
cornsoup has both an image and build path specified. A service can either be built to image or use an existing image, not both. (docker-compose 1.6.2)

Comment: @zx1986 for that you have to use new version of docker-compose.yml file refer this https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#upgrading Based on that updated my answer

Answer (score 80):

#### Option 1: Hinting default image name

The name of the image generated by *docker-compose* depends on the folder name by default but you can override it by using `--project-name` argument:

```
$ docker-compose --project-name foo build bar
$ docker images foo_bar
```

#### Option 2: Specifying image name

Once **docker-compose 1.6.0** is out, you may specify `build:` and `image:` to have an explicit image name (see [arulraj.net's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33951705/167897)).

#### Option 3: Create image from container

A third is to create an image from the container:

```
$ docker-compose up -d bar
$ docker commit $(docker-compose ps -q bar) foo_bar
$ docker-compose rm -f bar
```

Comment: `--project-name` does not seem to be accepted anymore. Using 1.23.2

Comment: @StevenVachon According to the docs, `--project-name` should work, but their examples use `-p`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name

Comment: --project-name was removed. You can use the env ```COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=foo docker-compose up```

Comment: I recently updated docker-compose (from 1.25.0 to 2.14.0) and the name changed from `PROJECT_NAME_IMAGE` to `PROJECT_NAME-IMAGE`. The underscore -> hyphen can be tricky to see (and explains why only old images are starting...)

Answer (score 39):

According to 3.9 version of Docker compose, you can use `image: myapp:tag` to specify name and tag.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: webapp:tag
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

Comment: Yep, this works as long as you have a build statement.  It kinda sucks that you just can't say image: nginx:latest   image-name: fred

Answer (score 33):

Depending on your use case, you can use an image which has already been created and specify it's name in `docker-compose`.

We have a production use case where our CI server builds a named Docker image. (`docker build -t <specific_image_name> .`). Once the named image is specified, our `docker-compose` always builds off of the specific image. This allows a couple of different possibilities:

1- You can ensure that where ever you run your `docker-compose` from, you will always be using the latest version of that specific image.

2- You can specify multiple named images in your `docker-compose` file and let them be auto-wired through the previous build step.

So, if your image is already built, you can name the image with `docker-compose`. Remove `build` and specify `image:`

```
wildfly:
  image: my_custom_wildfly_image
  container_name: wildfly_server
  ports:
   - 9990:9990
   - 80:8080
  environment:
   - MYSQL_HOST=mysql_server
   - MONGO_HOST=mongo_server
   - ELASTIC_HOST=elasticsearch_server
  volumes:
   - /Volumes/CaseSensitive/development/wildfly/deployments/:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
  links:
   - mysql:mysql_server
   - mongo:mongo_server
   - elasticsearch:elasticsearch_server
```

Answer (score 14):

after you build your image do the following:

`docker tag <image id> mynewtag:version`

after that you will see your image is no longer named `<none>` when you go `docker images`.

Comment: Is possible to specify the tags with docker-compose?

Comment: tags do not look to be supported at this time.

Comment: So I have to build the image and later re-tag it? Is not really useful, I hope the docker-compose fix this problem quickly?

Comment: if you are building a multi container environment yes.  if you are building a single container environment you can always go `docker build -t mytag:version .`

Answer (score 4):

you can customize the image name to build & container name **during docker-compose up** for this, you need to mention like below in the **docker-compose.yml** file. It will create an image & container with custom names.

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend_dev:
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    image: "mycustomname/sample:v1"
    container_name: mycustomname_sample_v1
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

Comment: `container_name` is what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

sudo docker-compose -p <project_name> build

assigns project name

Note: '-p' option comes before 'build' in the command

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/

Answer (score 2):

in docker-compose.yml, add `image: "YOUR-DESIRED-NAME"` line in your service e.g. if your service name is `wildfly` and you want to name your image as `wildfly_img`

> ```
> wildfly:
>   image: wildfly_img
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you specify image as well as build, then Compose names the built image with the webapp and optional tag specified in image:

```
image: webapp:tag
```

in the docker-compose file, it looks like.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  
  node-ecom:
    build: .
    image: "webapp:tag"
    container_name: node-ecom
    ports:
      - "4000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app:ro
      - /app/node_modules
      - /config/.env
    env_file:
      - ./config/.env
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

> ```
> version: '3.8'
> services:
>   app:
>     build: .
>     depends_on:
>       - postgres
>     ports:
>       - "8080:8080"
>     volumes:
>       - ./:/usr/src/app/
>     container_name: docker-compose-employees
>     image: [Docker-Hub-Username]/docker-compose:latest
> ```

The docker-compose app runs with a container name: `docker-compose-employees`

And an image called `[Docker-Hub-Username]/docker-compose:latest`

Answer (score 0):

If Jenkins is used the project-name can be defined using `stackName = prefix`.

jenkins:

```
stackName = 'foo'
```

docker:

```
services:
  bar:
```

So the name becomes `foo_bar`.