# How to pass current folder as the context to docker-compose.yml and then Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a central `Dockerfile`. It's locate in `~/base/Dockerfile`.
Let's say it only builds a simple `debian` image.

```
FROM debian
COPY test.js .
```

I also have a central `docker-compose.yml` file that uses this `Dockerfile`.
It is located in `~/base/docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
  test:
    build: ~/base/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

I also have a bash file that calls this `docker-compose.yml` from another directory.
For example:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
setup
```

`setup` is a bash file that is registered in the `/etc/bash.bashrc` as a global alias.

It contains these lines:

```
docker-compose -f ~/base/docker-compose.yml build
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose logs --f test
```

I can run `setup` from inside any folder, and it should build a container based on that `debian` image. And it does.

However, it shows me that the name of the container is `base_test_1`, which is the default convention of docker.

This shows that it uses `~/base/.` as the context.

How can I pass my current directory as the context?

Answer (score 1):

Created a docker-compose.yml in the same location . Added a context and the value used is a environment variable.

```
~/base$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "2.2"
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: ${contextdir}
      dockerfile: /home/myname/base/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

~/base$ cat Dockerfile
FROM python:3.6-alpine

COPY testfile.js .
```

Before triggering the docker-compose.yml build command, export the current working directory.

```
~/somehere$ ls
testfile.js


~/somehere$ export contextdir=$(pwd)

~/somehere$ docker-compose -f ~/base/docker-compose.yml build
Building test
Step 1/2 : FROM python:3.6-alpine
 ---> 815c1103df84
Step 2/2 : COPY testfile.js .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d0cc03f02bdf
Successfully built d0cc03f02bdf
Successfully tagged base_test:latest
```

my composefile and dockerfile are located in ~/base/ while the testfile.js is located in ~/somehere/ (which i am assuming as the current working directory)

Comment: At the end you still see that your container is named `base_test:latest`.

Comment: That is a different issue. The above addresses the  question on how to send a different context. For the image name , depending on the version ,this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33951705/8577085

Comment: try ../base/ in context prop