# multiple docker services from same Dockerfile - how to utilize caching

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a series of docker services that uses the same base Dockerfile, e.g.:

```
services:
  service_1:
    build:
      context: .
    ...
  service_2:
    build:
      context: .
    ...
```

On `Dockerfile`, I run a few installations:

```
FROM base_image

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        g++ \
        git \
...
```

How do I make sure that build for `Dockerfile` takes place only once? That is, after the `Dockerfile` build for `service_1`, the `service_2` uses a cached result?

Answer (score 1):

If you run `docker-compose build` without any arguments, it should simply use your locale cache already.

Though, on the other hand, there might also be some other options, depending on your real usage.

In case you can live with only one definition in the compose file (everything is the same) as here:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
```

You can also simply start with `docker-compose up -d --scale app=5` to get 5 instances running.

An other option is to re-use the image, as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35662191/5600652), though like this I never tried.

```yaml
services:
  service_1:
    build:
      context: .
    image: base_service
    depents_on:
      - app_base # to make shure it is builded
    ...
  service_2:
    image: base_service
    depents_on:
      - app_base # to make shure it is builded
    ...
```

Comment: `depends_on:` doesn't imply any ordering between one container building and another starting; `service_2` could start before `base_service` gets rebuilt.